# How do you take advantage of a composite index restricted to a vertex label?

Tags: gremlin, titan

Suppose I have defined a composite index and vertex label like so:

```
mgmt = g.getManagementSystem()
name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).make()
god = mgmt.getVertexLabel('god')
mgmt.buildIndex('byName',Vertex.class).addKey(name).indexOnly(god).buildCompositeIndex()
mgmt.commit()
```

How do I take advantage of this index in Gremlin?

Assuming it is something like `g.V('label','god').has('name','zeus')`, which is more performant?

1. `g.V('label','god').has('name','zeus')`
2. `g.V('name','zeus').has('label','god')`

Traditionally we would go with (2) because **name** is more highly selective than **label**, but is there something special about vertex labels that makes this untrue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work yet in TP2, but will work with TP3 (Titan 0.9 / next release). Currently you can do this:

`g.query().has('label','god').has('name','zeus').vertices()`

No idea about the performance profile still.

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/755

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you've already found out, that it's currently impossible in Gremlin and only available through the Query API. Regarding the performance: Your two approaches won't make a difference; under the hood both queries generate the same Cassandra/HBase query (or whatever storage backend you are using).

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, can you confirm that what you mean is that Gremlin queries are not indexed?

Comment: Confirmed. Gremlin2 doesn't use the index, Gremlin3 will use it. The only way to get around this limitation at the moment is to use the query API.